# About clang-format rule: "public: should be indented +1 space inside class"

Tags: c++, clang-format, cpplint

I use clang-format with style=Google to do format job. `clang-format` version is 12.0.1.
Formatted code likes this:

```
class SearchDoneService : public DoneService {
 public:
  explicit SearchDoneService(const string &);
```

But I donot get used with 2 spaces(`IndentWidth:2`). So I modify to `IndentWidth:4`.
Now Formatted code likes this:

```
class SearchDoneService : public DoneService {
   public:
    explicit SearchDoneService(const string &);
```

It seems the keywords(`public`, `private`, `protected`) always keep 1 space distance from member function of class.
But I use `cpplint` to do static checking. The screen prints this:

```
warning: public: should be indented +1 space inside class SearchDoneService
```

The warning is according to Google rule:

> Sections in public, protected and private order, each indented one space.

How to mute this warning if I want to change `IdentWidth` to 4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try setting `AccessModifierOffset`.

Comment: Change `AccessModifierOffset` value from `-1` to `-3`.It does perfectlly work!